# Order of Summarise Functions changes output in dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataset of coupon usage that ranges from 0 to any positive value.

I want to use dplyr to summarize the data.

However, I'm noticing that the order of the summarize functions affects the mean calculation. When the mean calculation is first, like in **A** below, the output is correct (the average of all non-zero coupons is 18.333).

However, when the mean calculation is last, like in **B** below the output is incorrect (it shows an average of 6 for all non-zero coupons). Can anyone explain what's going on and how I can fix **B** below to show the right answer?

Dataset

```
library(dplyr)
CouponDF <- data.frame(Coupon = c(0,0,10,10,20,40,20,10))
```

A

```
CouponDF %>%
    summarise(
    AvgCoupon = mean(Coupon[Coupon>0]),
    NoCoupon = sum(Coupon==0),
    Coupon = sum(Coupon>0)
    )
```

Outputs

```
   AvgCoupon NoCoupon Coupon
1  18.33333        2      6
```

B

```
CouponDF %>%
    summarise(
    NoCoupon = sum(Coupon==0),
    Coupon = sum(Coupon>0),
    AvgCoupon = mean(Coupon[Coupon>0]))
```

Outputs

```
     NoCoupon Coupon AvgCoupon
1        2      6         6
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Quick answer:** You redefine `Coupon` before you calculate `AvgCoupon`.

**How to fix:** Do not reuse the `Coupon` name.

**Why:**

Within you `summarise` function you redefine `Coupon`.
In Example **B** first you do

```
Coupon = sum(Coupon>0)
```

So `Coupon` now is 6.

`mean(Coupon[Coupon>0]))` now results in 6 as well as the following example shows.

```
Coupon <- 6
mean(Coupon[Coupon>0]) #6
```

Instead you could use:

```
CouponDF %>%
    summarise(
    without_coupon = sum(Coupon==0),
    with_coupon = sum(Coupon>0),
    ave_coupon = mean(Coupon[Coupon>0]))
```

Comment: I knew it'd be something easy that I missed. Thank you.